# PHP Version in Wamp and Command Line Windows not compatible

Tags: php, yii, wamp

So basically i am trying to run yii-framework on wamp server but required higher version of php (5.4 above). In my Wamp server, the php version is 5.5 which i have checked on browser (localhost). But the when i run it on windows, it fails because the windows version is only 5.3. It causes the yii framework fail too because when i type php requirements.php. it does not work.

Comment: and your programming problem is... what?

Comment: you can't upgrade the php windows version and change the fastcgi with new php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *Windows version of PHP* so basically you must have installed a version of PHP manually i.e. not with WAMPServer.

This will probably have added an entry on you PATH ( always a bad idea when using WAMPServer anyway as you can have many versions of PHP on your system at one time with WAMPServer)

Look at your PATH and if you must, amend it to point to the PHP in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}`

A better way is to remove any reference to PHP from the PATH environmant variable and write a simple batch file to add php to your path only when you want to, like this

Batch file saved in `C:\windows\phppath.cmd`

```
echo off
PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16
```

Assuming you have php5.4.16 on your wampserver install.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is with the path